# Checkmark in tableViewCell hidden when Scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

When i scroll Table, checkmark is hide. I know because of Reusing Cell, but I dont know how to fix. Pls help me. Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    StudentTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[StudentTableViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    if (_btnCancel.hidden == NO) {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I change check and uncheck in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cellCheck = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (_btnCancel.hidden == NO) {
        if (cellCheck.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
            cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            TeacherInfo *courseStudent = studentQuitArray[indexPath.row];
            [dict setObject:courseStudent.id_user forKey:@"student_id"];

            [studentDetail addObject:dict];

        } else {
            cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [studentDetail removeObject: studentQuitArray[indexPath.row]];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where you are making _btnCancel.hidden = YES??

Comment: My view have choose btn. Nomorl: button Cancel is hidde and cell is detail. When i click it, view show buttonCancel, and cell is AccessoryNone.
_btnCancel.hidden = YES just to check to show detail of cell or choose cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you scroll table view, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for particular cell will be called in which your are setting the `accessoryType` as None. Instead try like below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

    StudentTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[StudentTableViewCell alloc] init];
    }

    if (_btnCancel.hidden == NO) {
       TeacherInfo *courseStudent = studentQuitArray[indexPath.row];
       if ([studentDetail containsObject:courseStudent]) {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
       else {
           cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
       }
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    return cell;
}
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cellCheck = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (_btnCancel.hidden == NO) {
        if (cellCheck.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
            cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            TeacherInfo *courseStudent = studentQuitArray[indexPath.row];
            [dict setObject:courseStudent.id_user forKey:@"student_id"];

            [studentDetail addObject:dict];

        } else {
            cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [studentDetail removeObject: studentQuitArray[indexPath.row]];
        }

    }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are reusing cells then you need to save the state of each cell .Because every time you scroll up and down, TableView will bring back the previous cell that outside of the screen.

You can save selectable state in an array and read its index in cellForRowAtIndexpath to get the current state of the cell.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this by adding one boolean property like is-selected in your "TeacherInfo" NSObject class,and set true false based on table-row selection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

You need to add instance object of TeacherInfo instead of student id because your containedObject of array gives wrong result .

```
 - (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
        static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

        StudentTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[StudentTableViewCell alloc] init];
        }

        if (_btnCancel.hidden == NO) {
           TeacherInfo *courseStudent = studentQuitArray[indexPath.row];
           if ([studentDetail containsObject:courseStudent]) {
               cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
           else {
               cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
           }
        } else {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell* cellCheck = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    if (_btnCancel.hidden == NO) {
        if (cellCheck.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
            cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            TeacherInfo *courseStudent = studentQuitArray[indexPath.row];
            [studentDetail addObject:courseStudent];

        } else {
            cellCheck.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [studentDetail removeObject: studentQuitArray[indexPath.row]];
        }

    }
}
```